# How node.js guarantees that each worker will be on different cpu core?

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

In code `cluster.fork()`
How node.js guarantees that one will start on core-1 and second on core-2?

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    // Whats happening here? numCPUs is just a length, no reference to any core
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

And How client requests divided between workers?

Comment: The routing of requests to different workers is described in [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works).  Two possible methods - depends upon platform.

Answer (score 0):

Node does not make any guarantees that a worker will run on a particular cpu core. That is all handled and scheduled by the OS.

[Per the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works), client requests are divided in one of two ways:

> The cluster module supports two methods of distributing incoming connections.
>
> The first one (and the default one on all platforms except Windows), is the round-robin approach, where the master process listens on a port, accepts new connections and distributes them across the workers in a round-robin fashion, with some built-in smarts to avoid overloading a worker process.
>
> The second approach is where the master process creates the listen socket and sends it to interested workers. The workers then accept incoming connections directly.
>
> The second approach should, in theory, give the best performance. In practice however, distribution tends to be very unbalanced due to operating system scheduler vagaries. Loads have been observed where over 70% of all connections ended up in just two processes, out of a total of eight.

Comment: Then if we use any load balancer like `nginx` with two `node.js` processes on different port, will be similar as single port with two workers?

Comment: Then it may be possible that my `core-1` may be idle..:(

Comment: Possible? yes. Likely? no. The OS and CPU are very good at scheduling work across it's cores.

Comment: Is any way to make sure, each process will run on different core?